# How to select text between the specific occurrences of particular characters

Tags: regex

How can I select text between the specific occurrences of particular characters?

For example in below string:

> Lorem|Ipsum|is|simply|dummy|text|**A123**|the|printing|and|typesetting|industry|

I want to remove/replace text between the 6th and 7th occurrence of '|' character, i.e. the word 'A123'.

Is it possible to do so with Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify POSIX, PCRE or some other regex, but I'll assume PCRE. While regex doesn't let you select 'Nth occurrence of a character', you can always select Nth occurrence of a group if there is some pattern.

In your case, since pipe is a separator you can always select a group of any character followed by a pipe, and then select that group 6 times, then select anything until the next pipe to actually get your characters. Since you seem to be the most active in PHP, here's a PHP approach:

```
$data = "Lorem|Ipsum|is|simply|dummy|text|A123|the|printing|and|typesetting|industry|";
$foo_data = preg_replace('/^((.*?\|){6})[^|]+/', '$1FOO', $data);
echo $foo_data;  // Lorem|Ipsum|is|FOO|dummy|text|A123|the|printing|and|typesetting|industry|
```

You can remove the leading caret if you want to replace every seventh occurrence. You can also add brackets around the second part (`[^|]+`) if you need to manipulate/extract it.

Comment: In order to get your preg_replace to use the reference value before `FOO` in the replacement parameter, I found that this worked: `$foo_data = preg_replace('/^(?:(?:.*?\|){6})\K([^|]+)/','$1FOO', $data);`  or this: `$foo_data = preg_replace('/^((.*?\|){6})\K([^|]+)/','$3FOO', $data);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use counter quantifiers, usually denoted by numbers within curly braces (e.g., `pattern{7}`). For example this sed command replaces A123 with REP:

```
sed 's/\(\([^|]*|\)\{6\}\)[^|]*/\1REP/'
```